# How to quickly create <div> classes in VSCode

Tags: css

Generally new to web design and watching some tutorials on creating some backend for a project, getting really tired of writing out the  manually, I see youtubers do .classname and then the class with the div appears, but for some reason it isn't working for me? Any help would be appreciated.

Also, would it be easier to switch to Sublime, my buddies think that it is the way to go.

Cheers.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. Go to settings
2. Go to emmet under the Extensions section.
3. Click on 'Edit in settings.json'.
4. Write the following inside the 'emmet.includeLanguages' tag. Otherwise, paste the whole statement.
   "emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript":"javascriptreact" }
5. Save the settings.json file.

Answer (score 25):

Those videos are likely using [emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet). VS Code includes built-in support for emmet completions in html files. For example, typing `.classname` in an html file will trigger an emmet suggestion that expands to `<div class="classname"></div>` when you accept it

If you do not see this working:

- Make sure the document is in the `html` [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file)
- Try manually triggering suggestions after `.classname` using ctrl+space
- Make sure you have not disabled Emmet

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. my language mode was Django HTML so I turned it to HTML and now its working

Comment: Emmet was not needed, just click on bottom right on "Javascript", and then select "Javascript React".  Then typing ".row"  will insert the required div with the className.

Comment: This is working also when you need two or more classes, .e.g. `.btn.btn-primary`  will emmit `<div class="btn btn-primary"></div>`

Answer (score 13):

I tried everything written in the answers but it wouldnt work, I had to do the following;

go to settings in the bottom left, search for 'emmet'

scroll down to and tick:

'Trigger expansions on Tab'

then it works by typing .divClassName + Tab

Answer (score 5):

Check out this Cheat Sheet for VSC: 
[Cheat sheet for VSC](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 2):

The above answers didn't help me because VS code already came with Emmet installed, but I was missing the information on how to actually trigger it.

#### For an html element

Type the element e.g. div, h1, whatever, then press <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete it

#### For a class

Type the class name **beginning with a dot** then press <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete it.

For example type .myclass and hit tab and you'll get `<div class="myclass"></div>`

Note: if your class has spaces, use a dot in place of the space (e.g. for "my great class", you should type ".my.great.class" and hit tab)

#### Source

- This information is from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhRPdUv1ZrA&t=1m38s)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that VScode recognises your file as `HTML5` or `CSS` file. In my case I had emmet enabled, but while I could get emmet abbreviation in a `CSS` file, they wouldn't work in an `HTML` file. The issue was that I also had Django template extension installed and the file had Django template code as well, hence VScode considered the file as Django template file, not HTML. You can check this the status bar at the bottom of VScode. Once I changed the file from Django template to HTML by clicking on `Django Template` in the VScode status bar, emmet started working.

Answer (score 0):

Tried mentioned thing from emmet vs code document

- go-to .vscode >> settings.json
- add line `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true`

it worked for me for reference : [Emmet in visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)